# Manage many inputs between sibling components in React - best approach?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to this topic.

In the parent component App I have two siblings : SideMenu and Document

The idea is that the user inputs values (SideMenu) which will be renedered on the Document. There will be more than 20 inputs. Since this is the first time I do this sort of state management, what are the best or maybe easiest approaches for this attempt of project.

```
function App() {
const [fullName, setFullName] = useState("")
const [address, setAddress] = useState("")
  return (
      <div className='app'>
        <SideMenu />
        <Document />
      </div>
  )
}
export default App
```

```
const SideBar = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className='input-group'>
        <label>Full Name:</label>
        <input type='text' />
      </div>
      <div className='input-group'>
        <label>Address:</label>
        <input type='text' />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
const Document = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{fullName}</h1>
      <p>{address}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create an object for your form and store the form inputs in this object. Shared state can be stored in the most closest and common component (in your situation this is your parent component) according to your child components. [1]

When you make an update from a child component other child component that is sharing state will be syncronized and your state will be updated. You shouldn't use redux like state management tools unless you are need to set a global state.

I have made a revision for your example, this scenario allows you to pass the state in the parent component to the child components and update the state in the parent component from the child components.

I used a common event handler in the parent component, this functions captures the html event and we parse this event and update the state via this function. [2][3]

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

import SideBar from "./SideBar";
import Document from "./Document";

export default function App() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    fullName: "",
    address: "",
    postalCode: ""
  });

  function handleChange(event) {
    setValues({ ...values, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <SideBar values={values} setValues={handleChange} />
      <Document values={values} setValues={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
export default function Document({ values }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Document</h1>
      <p>Full Name: {values.fullName}</p>
      <p>Address: {values.address}</p>
      <p>Postal Code: {values.postalCode}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
export default function Sidebar({ setValues }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="input-group">
        <label>Full Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="fullName" onChange={setValues} />
      </div>
      <div className="input-group">
        <label>Address:</label>
        <input type="text" name="address" onChange={setValues} />
      </div>
      <div className="input-group">
        <label>Address:</label>
        <input type="text" name="postalCode" onChange={setValues} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Code Sandbox Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-74961591-wpmcnd

[1]: Passing Props to a component: https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/passing-props-to-a-component

[2]: Updating Objects in State: https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-objects-in-state

[3]: HTML Change Event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event

Answer (score 1):

1. The default, go-to solution would be to use a [container](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/container-components-in-react/) component that controls your form inputs state (this would be `App` in your case). Just pass the values and setters down one level by props and everything should be ok, simple and predictable.
2. If things start to get complicated then libraries such as [Formik](https://formik.org/) or [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/) help a lot. When it comes to managing multiple or complex forms that may also need validation they are your best bet. I suggest you take this approach.
3. Using Redux for this kind of situation is a [huge anti-pattern](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/). Redux global store should be only used for **global** state, not local form state.
4. [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) is well suited when you need to pass data to multiple deeply nested children. This way you do not need to pass props dozens of levels down the tree. However, it is usually used by 3rd party libraries such as the ones mentioned above (all of them).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Formik`](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik) library for handling many inputs. Wrap both components inside Formik and use formik's methods.

```
import { Formik } from 'formik';

     <Formik
       initialValues={{ fullName: '', address: '' }}
       onSubmit={(values) => {
           alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
       }}
     >
       {({handleChange, values, handleSubmit}) => (
         <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
           <div className='app'>
               <SideMenu 
                  handleChange={handleChange} 
               />
               <Document values={values} />
           <button type="submit">Submit</button>
         </form>
       )}
     </Formik>
```

You dont need to create multiple states for each input. `handlChange` will handle itself. You just need add `name` or `id` attribute to input. Also you can access values of each input using the `values` parameter like `values.fullName`.

```
const SideBar = ({handleChange}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className='input-group'>
        <label>Full Name:</label>
        <input 
          type='text' 
          onChange={handleChange}
          name="fullName"
        />
      </div>
      <div className='input-group'>
        <label>Address:</label>
        <input 
          type='text' 
          onChange={handleChange} 
          name="address"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

const Document = ({values}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{values.fullName}</h1>
      <p>{values.address}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```